# I can not use flashvars flash

Tags: flash

HI there I am trying to use flashvars in my application but unfortantly I get errors

```
package com.endseven {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;

    public class RTMPStream extends MovieClip {
        var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;
        protected var sMediaServerURL:String = "rtmp://hostname/test";
        protected var sStreamName:String = paramObj.toString();

        protected var oConnection:NetConnection;
        protected var oMetaData:Object = new Object();
        protected var oNetStream:NetStream;
        protected var oVideo:Video;

        /* the constructor */
        public function RTMPStream():void {

            NetConnection.prototype.onBWDone = function(oObject1:Object) {
                trace("onBWDone: " + oObject1.toString()); // some media servers are dumb, so we need to catch a strange event..
            }

        }

        /* triggered when meta data is received. */
        protected function eMetaDataReceived(oObject:Object) {
            trace("MetaData: " + oObject.toString()); // debug trace..
        }

    }

}
```

The errors I get is:

Line 13 1119: Access of possibly undefined property root through a reference with static type Class.

How can use this proberly

The line that have error is this:
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;

What I want to archive is to set the sStreamName from pargrams within a  html/PHP file for a specific user.

Comment: The use of `prototype` is deprecated since As2.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code outside of any method:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;
```

You can think about this as a static context. In that context, member variables (like `root`) do not exist yet.

You should declare the variable, but assign the value later in the constructor. Something like this:

```
public class RTMPStream extends MovieClip {
    var paramObj:Object;

    /* the constructor */
    public function RTMPStream():void {
        paramObj = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;
```